# How to create jQuery Tabs out of Markdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, markdown

I'm currently running a PHP based Content-Management-System that generates its HTML content with the help of [Markdown Extra](http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/extra/). Most of the content is structured by headings and sub-headings which results in a very long page. At the beginning of each page I create a table of contents with the help of a list and [Markdown Extra's](http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/extra/) *Header Id Attribute*.

In oder to shorten the length of a page view I'd like to use the jQuery's [Tabs Plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs) on the first level of headings.

The Problem is that the output of [Markdown Extra](http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/extra/) is not compatible with what the jQuery [Tabs Plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs) is expecting because [Markdown Extra](http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/extra/) is not wrapping the content of a section into a separate div-tag.

Is there a way how to make those two libraries work together?

#### EDIT

This is what the HTML output is looking like:

```
 <p>Some intro text...</p>
 <h3>Table of content</h3>
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#sub1">Topic 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#sub2">Topic 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#sub3">Topic 3</a></li>
 </ul>
 <h3 id="sub1">Topic 1</h3>
 <p>The content of this topic.</p>
 <h3 id="sub2">Topic 2</h3>
 <p>The content of this topic.</p>
 <h3 id="sub3">Topic 3</h3>
 <p>The content of this topic.</p>
```

.. and this is the corresponding Markdown code:

```
Some intro text...

###Table of content###

* [Topic 1](#sub1)
* [Topic 2](#sub2)
* [Topic 3](#sub3)

###Topic 1### {#sub1}

The content of this topic.

###Topic 2### {#sub2}

The content of this topic.

###Topic 3### {#sub3}

The content of this topic.
```

#### Solution

With a little help of cobbal I made this jQuery statement that will transform the Markdown markup into something that the Tabs plugin will work with:

```
  $("#tabs :header").each(function() 
  {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    if(id=="") return;    
    var div = $("<div>");
    var tagName = this.tagName;    
    $(this).nextAll().each(function()
    {
      if(this.tagName==tagName) return false;
      div.append(this);
    });
    $(this).removeAttr("id");
    div.attr("id", id);
    $(this).before(div);
    div.prepend(this);
  });
```

But the fact that I need to transform the markup to fit the Tabs plugin rather than just tell the Tabs plugin that it should select its content in a different way may made this solution not the ideal one.

Comment: could you post a code sample of how the output of markdown Extra looks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on your document.ready

```
$("#sub1,#sub2,#sub3").each(function() {
    var containerDiv = $("<div>").attr("id", $(this).attr("id") + "div");
    $(this).before(containerDiv);
    containerDiv.append(this);
});
```

and change your markdown to

```
...
* [Topic 1](#sub1div)
* [Topic 2](#sub2div)
* [Topic 3](#sub3div)
...
```

Comment: this will only wrap the headings into a div .. but thanks anyway based on your hint I was able to make my own jQuery statement

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you could wrap the table of contents in a div yourself.

Half way down the Markdown Extra page that you linked to it shows how to insert Markdown inside a div, like this:

PHP Markdown Extra gives you a way to put Markdown-formatted text inside any
block-level tag. You do this by adding a markdown attribute to the tag with 
the value 1 — which gives markdown="1" — 
like this:

```
<div markdown="1">
This is *true* markdown text.
</div>
```

The markdown="1" attribute will be stripped and the ’s content will be converted from Markdown to HTML. The end result will look like this:

```
<div>

<p>This is <em>true</em> markdown text.</p>

</div>
```

Comment: But this would distroy the maintainability I as looking for when I started using Markdown...